# Name and function for the following matrix operation in R

Tags: python, r, matrix

I am trying to reproduce this [50 x 50] matrix generated with Python as:

```
n = 50                                         
a = np.linspace(-5, 5, n).reshape(-1,1)
b = a
np.sum(a**2, 1).reshape(-1, 1) + np.sum(b**2, 1)
```

using R. The problem is that the result is some sort of matrix, which cannot be reproduced through:

```
n = 50     
a = seq(-5, 5, length.out = n)
b = a
a^2 + b^2
```

which generates a vector.

I am not familiar with the object names in Python, but I see that `np.sum(a**2, 1).reshape(-1, 1)` produces what looks like a [50 x 1] column vector:

```
array([[  2.50000000e+01],
       [  2.30008330e+01],
       ...
       [  2.10849646e+01],
       [  2.30008330e+01],
       [  2.50000000e+01]])
```

while `np.sum(b**2, 1)`:

```
array([  2.50000000e+01,   2.30008330e+01,   2.10849646e+01,
         1.92523948e+01,   1.75031237e+01,   1.58371512e+01,
         ...
         1.27551020e+01,   1.42544773e+01,   1.58371512e+01,
         1.75031237e+01,   1.92523948e+01,   2.10849646e+01,
         2.30008330e+01,   2.50000000e+01])
```

looks like the transposed of that same vector. So we have an operation of the form [50 x 1] * [1 x 50] = [50 x 50].

What is the generic name of this operation? And how can I reproduce it in R?

Comment: It's not overly clear what the result is you want, but maybe `outer(a^2,b^2,FUN=\`+\`)` ?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you. If you want to post it as an answer, please include the generic name of the operation. I'll be happy to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `?outer` I believe. As per the help file, it returns:

> The outer product of the arrays X and Y ... the array A with dimension
>   c(dim(X), dim(Y))

So, for your specific example, try:

```
outer(a^2,b^2,FUN=`+`)
#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#[1,] 50.00000 48.00083 46.08496  ...to col 50
#[2,] 48.00083 46.00167 44.08580  ...to col 50
#[3,] 46.08496 44.08580 42.16993  ...to col 50
# ...to row 50
```

Comment: Outer product in matrices I believe entails multiplication of elements. Here we are summing.

Comment: While I get what you're saying that a product is strictly multiplication, the help file seems to contradict that in its argument list: "*FUN - a function to use on the outer products*" - similarly, wikipedia - "*In some programming languages, given a two-argument function f (or a binary operator), the outer product of f and two one-dimensional arrays A and B is a two-dimensional array C such that C[i,j] = f(A[i],B[j])*" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product - implying that another function can be used in place of multiplication and still call it an outer product.

Comment: I get it, and will ultimately accept your answer, unless there is another answer including a non-programming strictly mathematical term for the operation in question.